# echo multidimensional array by element

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to echo specific parts of a multidimensional array.

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [name] => Fiora's Inquisitors
        [tier] => DIAMOND
        [queue] => RANKED_SOLO_5x5 [entries] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                [playerOrTeamId] => 385868
                [playerOrTeamName] => Cowsep
                [division] => IV
                [leaguePoints] => 95
                [wins] => 35
                [losses] => 22
                [isHotStreak] =>
                [isVeteran] =>
                [isFreshBlood] =>
                [isInactive] =>
            )
        )
    )
)
```

I can echo "tier" with `echo $rank[0]['tier']`
But how can I echo "division"?

Comment: You do it the same way as you accessed `tier` nothing special to it.

Comment: no, if I do that noting is showing and gives me this error: Notice: Undefined index: division

Comment: How do you try to access it?

Comment: you mean this? echo $rank[0]['division'];

Comment: Here is the mistake. See the duplicate under "Analyse var_dump() / print_r() / var_export() output" there you see how you correctly access the value. Your index is nested inside other arrays.